# Mongoose and sql comparison

Tags: sql, mongoose, comparison

This is a multi question

From a mongoose result I have several items in the result which I get through `result.length`.

How can I get specific items e.g.

```
Person.find({'exployment.office':'Greenway'})
        .exec(function(err, result){
            //from the result, how can i get those items with
            result.length would give me the number of items in the result
            but how can i get a specific item without having to use loop to get 
            the specific item within the result
            //There are like fifty people in the result,
            //how can i get the number of items in result
        });
```

In SQL, I have a query like this

```
select * 
from table1, table2 
where table2.field2 = value1 
  and table2.field2 = table1.field2
  and table1.value1 = value3
```

e.g.

```
select * 
from city, state 
where state.name = 'xxy' 
  and state.id = city.state_id
  and city.name != 'yyy'
```

How can this be converted to mongoose?

In SQL if I want to select people whose first name are e.g. Smith, Queen I can use things like

```
select * 
from table 
where first_name in (Smith, Queen)
```

This would give me result for people whose first_name matches SMith and Queen

How can I do this in mongoose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * 
from Person 
where first_name in (Smith, Queen)
```

Would simply be this using [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/):

```
Person.find({'first_name': { $in: ['Smith', 'Queen']}}) ...
```

Next one:

```
select * 
from city, state 
where state.name = 'xxy' 
  and state.id = city.state_id
  and city.name != 'yyy'
```

Using mongoose, you would need to use [populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) and create the schemas with [ref](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#refs-to-children) relationships.

```
City.find({ "name": { $ne: "yyy"} }).populate({
    "path": "state",
    "match": { "state.name": "xxy" }
}) ...
```

Next one:

```
Person.find({'exployment.office':'Greenway'})
        .exec(function(err, result){
            //from the result, how can i get those items with
            result.length would give me the number of items in the result
            but how can i get a specific item without having to use loop to get 
            the specific item within the result
            //There are like fifty people in the result,
            //how can i get the number of items in result
        });
```

You would filter as much as you can before you `exec` the query to get the records you need rather than filter after you get all in the result. `result.length` sure would give you the count although you could get the count via something like this;

```
 Person.count({first_name: "Smith"}).exec() ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much very helpful

Comment: You are welcome. If my answer helped you feel free to upvote or simply accept it, this would help other people as well finding it etc.